# What is wrong with the layout of div's?

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to html and css and I have a trouble with understanding of the layout. Here is an example which I have created to show my problem.

What I would expect is for #bottom to be inside the #page but it is below it. Additionally the div #else which I would thought should be below the #page is in the same space as the #bottom.

Could you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

```css
header {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
  height: 20vh;
    width: 80vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#page {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#main  {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 67.5vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#side  {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 21.5vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#bottom  {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#else  {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
        <header>
        </header>
        <div id="main">
        </div>       
        <div id="side">
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="else">
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey, since you are new to css you should know that the border takes space, so if your width is 50px with borders, then it is really 52px. secondly display:block will have no effect with float

Answer (score 0):

Remove float left from `#bottom`

```
#bottom  {
  background-color:green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

here is the link: https://codepen.io/Dholu_Effect/pen/PoqByQa?editors=1100

Also I would sugges you to use Flex-box, it will make things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why did you put this float:left in your footer.If you remove it everything should work fine

```
#bottom  {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made few adjustments in your code, I hope that is fine with you:

> Note: View in full screen mode for more clarity.

```css
#page {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
header {
    display: absolute;
    margin: 0px auto;
  height: 20vh;
    width: 80vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#main  {  
  float: left;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 67.5vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#side  {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 21.5vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#bottom  { 
  height: 4vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color:green;
}

#else  {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
        <header>header
        </header>
        <div id="main">main
        </div>       
        <div id="side">side
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">bottom
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="else">else
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body>
    <div id="page">
        <header>Header</header>
        <div id="main">Main</div>       
                <div id="side">Side</div>
      <div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
    </div>
    <div id="else">Else</div>
</body>
```

And the css

```
header {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
  height: 20vh;
    width: 80vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#page {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#main  {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 67.5vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#side  {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 21.5vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#bottom  {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color:#ddd;
}

#else  {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://codepen.io/erwinagpasa/pen/ZEGjqjY

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can see this**

```css
        header {
            display: block;
            margin: 0px auto;
            height: 20vh;
            width: 90vw;
            background-color: #011a2f
        }

        #page {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 90vw;

        }

        #main {
            float: left;
            height: 60vh;
            width: 67.5vw;
            background-color: #323232
        }

        #side {
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-left: 2px;
            height: 60vh;
            width: 22.5vw;
            background-color: #ff1e56;
        }

        #bottom {
            height: 5vh;
            width: 90vw;
            background-color: #000000;
        }

        #else {
            height: 10vh;
            width: 90vw;
            background-color: #ffac41;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="page">
        <header></header>
        <div id="main"></div>
        <div id="side"></div>
        <div id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="else"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest i can do for you to understand it in your beginner level

```css
*{
box-sizing:border-box; /* this will let the border/padding be included in the elements size */
}
#page {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
header {
    display: inline-block;
    
    margin: 0 10%;
  height: 20vh;
    width: 80%;/* changed to percentage which is more logic to follow its parent not the viewport width */
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#main  {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 67.5%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin:0;
  margin-left:5%;
}

#side  {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px; 
  height: 60vh;
  width: calc(22.5% - 6px);/* 2 for the margin left, 4 for the borders*/
  border: 1px solid green;
  
}

#bottom  {
  /*float: left;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 90%; /* percentage */
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#else  {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
        <header>
        </header>
        <div id="main">
        </div>       
        <div id="side">
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="else">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you use flexbox. Here is a quick responsive design I did with HTML5 selectors. Since you're new to HTML/CSS, I would suggest you start learning this way and avoid so many `div` classes, as that doesn't work that great with accessibility, which is a huge issue in today's development world.

And [here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/wvaxYbO) you can play with.

```css
/* Roboto Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap');

html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; /* Avoid the IE 10-11 `min-height` bug. */
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* Prevent Chrome, Opera, and Safari from letting these items shrink to smaller than their content's default minimum size. */
  background: darkgray;  
}

header {
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ccc;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 300;  
}

main {
  display: flex;
}

article {
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

aside {
  width: 30%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Prevent Chrome, Opera, and Safari from letting these items shrink to smaller than their content's default minimum size. */
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  main > article, aside {
    width: 100%;
  }
}






* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  background: #333333;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <main>    
    <article>
      <h3>Current Article</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit vero quibusdam maxime magnam rerum nemo provident? Commodi, non! Ad facilis, doloribus voluptatum alias nostrum voluptatibus enim libero, distinctio nam sunt similique pariatur nesciunt accusantium eveniet perferendis ea doloremque molestiae culpa consequuntur quia aspernatur, itaque voluptate? Voluptatem magni delectus harum totam.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga rerum repudiandae error eveniet est explicabo, nihil eum. Inventore laboriosam consectetur dolor consequatur. Unde in doloribus repellendus dolorum perferendis officia hic?</p>
      <p>Dicta molestias doloremque, corrupti dolorum ipsum ea perferendis neque a, animi magnam ab sint impedit repudiandae aspernatur vel natus cum suscipit vero nisi nihil blanditiis iste laborum. Eum, sunt quo!</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
        <li>Nisi doloremque ut deserunt?</li>
        <li>Impedit aliquam itaque placeat.</li>
        <li>Sit incidunt iure assumenda.</li>
        <li>Inventore fuga optio perferendis!</li>
      </ul>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus illum aut quia alias delectus labore, maiores, excepturi quae nisi a non consequuntur! Officia fugiat enim nostrum molestias ipsa! Deleniti, repudiandae!</p>
      <p>Illo, reprehenderit? Ipsum velit aut, ducimus minima in accusamus aperiam ex cumque recusandae tenetur architecto nemo repellat asperiores eum. Corrupti blanditiis, odio sequi ea ducimus ipsam temporibus culpa asperiores dicta.</p>
      <p>Maxime alias, natus veritatis quis mollitia itaque voluptate iure neque dolore, expedita eaque, in ea sunt quibusdam ut ducimus fugit doloribus! Corporis molestiae nobis quae nesciunt inventore alias sed error.</p>
      <p>Id est repellendus pariatur harum, hic sequi vero ab mollitia corporis nisi, consequuntur eaque doloremque, suscipit nobis velit dolore totam exercitationem facere voluptas iure? Temporibus eius minus vero aut cumque!</p>
    </article>
    <aside>
      <h4>In other news:</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Placeat, culpa.</p>
      <p>Molestiae, officiis non esse perspiciatis provident a doloribus dignissimos sint!</p>
      <p>Inventore nihil illum maxime ipsa repudiandae quia omnis quae consequuntur!</p>
    </aside>
  </main>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  Company Name | All rights reserved &copy;2020
</footer>
```